# How can I pass data to a method in a different class?

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm a noobie when it comes to programming still, decided I wanted to test my limits and create a tic tac toe game. I'm sure there are much better ways of doing what I'm trying to do but I'm only still learning. When testing what I have so far, I've been running into this problem where a user is asked to input a position (the positions are 1-9, and these positions will eventually be used to tell the program where to put the users X or O). I have 2 classes right now, the Main class and the Board class. After a bit of debugging by putting a stop marker, I've come to realize that when I'm calling a method from my board class in my main class, the data that was put into the arguments for the method isn't carrying over.

Main Class:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Board board = new Board();

            bool hasWon = false;

            string p1;
            string p2;
            string pos;
            int turn = 2;

            Console.Write("Please enter a name for player 1: ");
            p1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Please enter a name for player 2: ");
            p2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

            while (hasWon == false) {
                if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine(p1 + "'s Turn / You are X's");
                    board.DisplayBoard();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please selecet a position: ");
                    board.SetPos(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Position correctly set: " + board.GetPos());
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine(p2 + "'s Turn / You are O's");
                    board.DisplayBoard();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please selecet a position: ");
                    board.SetPos(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Position correctly set: " + board.GetPos());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Board Class:

```
public class Board {

        private string pos = "";
        private string badPos = "";
        public void DisplayBoard() {
            Console.WriteLine(" 1 | 2 | 3 ");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            Console.WriteLine(" 4 | 5 | 6");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            Console.WriteLine(" 7 | 8 | 9 ");
        }

        public void SetPos(string pos) {
            if (this.pos.Length > 1 || this.pos.Length < 1) {
                this.pos = badPos;
                IncorrectPosition();
            } else if (!this.pos.Contains("1") || this.pos.Contains("2") || this.pos.Contains("3") || this.pos.Contains("4") ||
                this.pos.Contains("5") || this.pos.Contains("6") || this.pos.Contains("7") || this.pos.Contains("8") ||
                this.pos.Contains("9")) {
                this.pos = badPos;
                IncorrectPosition();
            } else {
                this.pos = pos;
            }
        }

        public string GetPos() {
            return pos;
        }

        /*public void setTurn(int turn) {
            turn = this.turn;
        }*/

        private void IncorrectPosition() {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(badPos + " is not a correct position");
            Console.Write("Please enter a position: ");
            SetPos(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }
```

To be more specific, the issue is happening in the Main class. When the user is asked to enter a position, they do so by entering a number 1-9. In the Board class, there is a method called SetPos, which will be used to determine where to place the X or the O later on when I develop that. However, I also have a method that makes sure what the user entered was a number 1-9. I don't want to convert it into an integer, I want it to stay a string. Whenever the user enters anything for the position, nothing gets carried over. When using the stop marker and going through the program step by step, in the watch list where I can see what values are being assigned to what variables, my pos variable does get assigned to what I've inputted, but is then lost thus repeating the SetPos and IncorrectPosition. When the IncorrectPosition is being displayed to the console, it shows

*is not a correct position

 Please enter a position:*

Inside the SetPos() method, I have tried a few things to fix this, one of which being I've added a badPos variable, meaning if any of the first two things in my if statement are true, then the value that was passed through the SetPos() method in my Main class would be assigned to *badPos*, but when printed out to the console, there is no value being displayed on the screen, which is another way of telling me that no value was ever assigned.

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, and any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `if (this.pos.Length > 1 || this.pos.Length < 1) ` you are checking `this.pos` (the class field) while you _should_ be checking `pos` (the function argument). (For starters. Of course there is plenty room for improvement. But this is the major malfunction.)

Comment: BTW: You never change `turn` nor `hasWon`. So your Player 1 will be playing forever ... but I guess, you planned on doing this after you fixed the above error, right? Your whole `Board` class doesn't make much sense as of now.

Comment: @Fildor Just so I can understand better, why does checking this.pos.Length not work? the pos variable in the board class isn't assigned a value until the position value passed by the user is checked and made sure that it is indeed a correct position. If I instead checked the pos variable, instead of this.pos, wouldn't it still show it's empty? (Once again this is just so I can further understand why this works the way it does.) And yes, I haven't implemented any way to win or switch turns yet. I primarily wanted to fix this issue before I continued.

Comment: Well, you kind of answered your own question: _"the pos variable in the board class isn't assigned a value until the position value passed by the user is checked"_ just that you do _not_ check the passed position value. You check the board class's position field, which is - as you kow - not set, yet. And as is, never will. `this.pos` is the pos field of the board class, not the method argument. You can easily check that by renaming the argument to something else. That would be less confusing.

Comment: BTW: I just saw that you handle an invalid entry recursively. I don't think that is a particularly bad problem in this case. But you should consider using a loop instead. If you use such a construct in a setting without user interaction and the recursion depth increases ever more, you'll potentially end up in a stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe the misconception is caused by the term `this` itself. [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) refers to the current instance of the class the method is called on. It does _not_ refer to "this method's argument xyz".

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
public void SetPos(string pos) 
{
    if (this.pos.Length > 1 || this.pos.Length < 1) 
    {   
        // by using "this" you are checking "pos" in the class and not the provided value
        // I'll assume that that "badPos" here is a placeholder as this would result in this.pos getting set to null because a variable named badPos has yet to be declared in this scope
        this.pos = badPos; 
        IncorrectPosition();
    } 
    else if (!this.pos.Contains("1") || this.pos.Contains("2") 
        || this.pos.Contains("3") || this.pos.Contains("4") 
        || this.pos.Contains("5") || this.pos.Contains("6") 
        || this.pos.Contains("7") || this.pos.Contains("8") 
        || this.pos.Contains("9")) 
    {
            // why not just use an int here? also if I'm reading this correctly 2 through 9 will make this true and then tell the player that this is a bad position. 
            this.pos = badPos;
            IncorrectPosition();
    } 
    else 
    {
        this.pos = pos;
    }
}
```

Here is how I would do it:

```csharp
public void SetPos(int pos) 
{
    if (pos > 0 && pos < 10)
    {
        // when you devise a way to store the board state you would check if the position is occupied here and any other checks you want to do - before assigning the value
        this.pos=pos;
    }
    else
    {
        this.pos = null;
        IncorrectPosition();
    }
}
```

So, I used an int and you said you didn't want to use that - I think you will find when you try to construct a data structure to hold your board state - math will be unavoidable. For you use there is no difference between the string "1" and the int 1 except that one is a lot harder to validate then the other

I digress

The reason your checks always went to "bad position" is that in your first if clause by using 'this' you check if the **class's** copy of `pos.length` is greater or less than 1 - as it is null at the time of the check its length is 0 and so the clause returns true.

you need to refer the passed variable by just doing `pos` without the `this` in front of it.